# Does AMD support rdmsr command?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

The recipe in yocto seems only support Intel:

https://git.congatec.com/yocto/meta-openembedded/blob/b9691ddce65f86387ca35a070981c3ac710541bb/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/msr-tools/msr-tools_1.3.bb

or it also support AMD CPU?